# Elements overlapping eachother on window resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

On [this template](http://d.dancodes.com.ar/private/thrace/) I've built using [Foundation](http://Foundation.zurb.com), everything looks correct and responsive except for both navigation bars. They're both on their own `<div class="row">`, yet they overlap eachother on window resize.

(There is a `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)` that is supposed to make it look even cleaner, if it helps at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if you open the page on chrome with the developer tools or in firefox with firebug, you can see that when you make the page smaller than 767px width, is when the problems enters, due your @media only screen and (max-width: 767px). i would recommend to check that css cause if you removed it from the html you get a better result, so you may check what attributes inside that css are making your div crazy.

Comment: Thanks! I added an answer myself just to keep a record of the steps I took.

Answer (score 0):

try adding foundation.css (around line 148) .row class height to 140px and moving main-links somewhere inside top of the main-content? That code seriously need either playing around with heights/margin or div blocks imo :)

Edit: roughly editing foundation.css lines is not what you need, make separate css class for that specific height setting and trigger usage of it with correct media query (width which causes problem to occur). That way you can tune any classes you like around the top navigation, its not pretty but it gets things work.

Answer (score 0):

As [Jorge Aguilar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11763665/101066) said, the problem lied in a `float: none` that was applied to every `<li>`. Furthermore, I used a `width: 100%` property to stretch the elements across the entire screen (like it originally was with the floats, but without the overlapping)